# Error parsing short array syntax when using json_encode()

Tags: php, json, encoding

I am sharing my work with some team. On my side, this line `json_encode(['Succeeded'])` works perfectly, on the team side this fails with this message

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in /home/app/file.php on line *
```

Why is this so ?

Comment: The code you show only works in PHP 5.4+.  Your team probably has a lower version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you might have two different versions of PHP installed.

Short array syntax was introduced in version 5.4.0.  See http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

Therefore, the following will probably work on both:

```
json_encode(array('Succeeded'));
```

Comment: I knew that reading the 5.4.0 new features page the other day would come in handy!! :D

Answer (score 2):

That syntax is supported only as of php 5.4.0:

http://php.net/releases/5_4_0.php

Comment: I don't think so, it is literal array syntax